# Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using **Nextjs with Typescript.**

I want to get the posts using the Get request. I am getting an error on this line of my code:

```
render() {
const {posts}= this.state
```

The error message is:

> Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface AbcState {
  posts: any[];
}

export class PostL extends Component<AbcState>{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({ posts: response.data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.setState({ errorMsg: 'Error retrieving data' })
      })

  }

  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        List of Posts
                    {
          posts.length ?
            posts.map(post => <div key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>) : null
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PostL
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the props and state types when you define your component?

Comment: Yes, I tried with this :
interface AbcState {
    posts: any[]; 
   
  }
export class PostL extends Component < AbcState>{

Comment: The first generic type argument is the *props*, not the state.

Comment: Even after changing it to props, the error still persists. What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
export class PostL extends Component<any, any>
```

Then constrain your props and state to the actual shape.

Comment: That solves the problem bu why doesn't the below code solve the error? Isn';t it a bad practice to not mention the state and props? :
interface Props {
posts: any[];

export class PostL extends Component<{}, Props>

Comment: Because there you assert that the state for your component is of type `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your component to have value in the state then you need to define it like this.

General example:

```
interface MyProps {
  ...
}

interface MyState {
  value: string
}

class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  ...
}
```